# How to make the right column fixed, with fixed header and centered content

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Zz4EF/1/ for an example of what the layout looks like. I have replaced all images with the same basic image for testing purposes.

The layout uses a full-width header and centered content with a maximum width of 1440px. I would like the right column (the `aside` with id `sidebar`) to stay fixed while the left column (the content column) scrolls naturally.

As you can see from the jsFiddle I have everything except for the fact that the right column is scrolling like the left one. I cannot use `position: fixed` on the right column because I don't know the total width of the screen (wrapper is maximum 1440px but the body width could be larger) so I wouldn't know what numbers to put in `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` positioning.

I am looking for a solution without javascript if at all possible.

**Edit 2013-09-09**: after trying many things and asking many people I figured that the only way to do this is to use Javascript and that is not a path I want to take for this particular case. I have decided to alter my design for something simpler but I am leaving the question open in case someone has a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQWKF/)**.

I've created a new example (that means that I didn't use yours) because your code was a mess =) (not offense).

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<section>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
<aside></aside>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    padding: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

section {
    width: 75%;
    height: 95%; /* For browsers that doesn't support calc function */
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    float: left;
    background: orange;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
}

section > article {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}

aside {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The rest of the CSS code is a little "*CSS reset*".

Cheers,
Leonardo

---

**EDIT:** I've edited the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQWKF/3/)**.

Comment: Yeah the code is part of a Wordpress theme so there's a ton of things going on at the same time. I updated your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qQWKF/2/) a bit. I'm only missing the part where the red column (the aside) is right next to the yellow column (the content).

Comment: I've edited the Fiddle =). The problem was the ´div#wrapper´. The width of that element was set to a fixed value. The same happened with the ´section´ element and with the ´aside´ element. Check the post to see the edited demo.

Comment: I have just noticed your edit. The div `wrapper` cannot have `width: 100%` as it is limited to 1440px (I put 500px in the fiddle so it wouldn't stretch it). The `section` element can be a % but the `aside` must be 300px (or equivalent for the fiddle) as well. This is so that if a user has a screen larger than 1440px the wrapper will be in the center of the screen.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that... But well, you don't have to worried about the `max-width`, just add that property (in this case, it will be `max-width: 1440px;`. I've made the next changes in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQWKF/5/). Check it and tell me if that was that you want.

Comment: It is but when I look at it on a larger screen the red column is separated from the yellow one. Try setting `max-width` for the `wrapper` div to 500px then you'll see what I mean. The red column should be stuck to the yellow one and there should be a space right of the yellow column - but if that works then the text isn't fixed anymore. Unless there's a javascript solution for fixing the text in the red column?